# Bash program that displays each line of a file in reverse order

Tags: bash

I have a file

```
foo
boo
stuff
```

and I would like to have

```
oof
oob
ffuts
```

Is there any bash utility that will do this for me?

Comment: tac reverses the whole file. That is, it would print last line as first. op wants to reverse each line..

Comment: @Avinash Raj why didn't you put your answer? I can't accept it here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `rev` command.

```
rev file
```

From `man rev`

> The rev utility copies the specified files to standard output,
>   reversing the order of characters in every line.  If no files are
>   specified, standard input is read.

Comment: This program is completely new for me... I searched for it but found nothing. I don't know what a stupid animal downvoted my question..